# Expand List within List

Tags: python, list, expand

Is there an easy way in python to expand lista into listb?

```
lista = [['apples', ['bob','mary'], 2020],
['bananas', ['john', 'bill', 'chris'], 2019]]


listb = [['apples', 'bob', 2020],
['apples', 'mary', 2020],
['bananas', 'john', 2019],
['bananas', 'bill', 2019],
['bananas', 'chris', 2019]]
```

Comment: What is your criteria for "easy way"? Have you tried something already?

Comment: Explain  what you mean by "expand"? Show expected output

Comment: `[[a, x, c] for a, b, c in lista for x in b]`

Comment: By "expand", I mean that I want to convert lista into listb and I'm looking for solutions.

Comment: @alaniwi it is always better to use clear names, `[[fruit, name, year] for fruit, names, year in lista for name in names]`

Comment: I'm a beginner, just didn't know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just wanna repeat the first and last elements for all the middle elements? This should work:

```
listb = []
for lia in lista:
  for item in lia[1]:
    listb.append([lia[0],item,lia[2]])
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Is there a name for what this is called?

Comment: @user2426152 I don't know:) If this solved you problem you can "accept" the answer by klicking the check mark.